# PHP get mime type poor performance

Tags: php, performance, mime

Does anyone know why getting mime type in PHP is relatively slow and memory-hungry? It's even much slower than `getimagesize()`, which also includes the mime type (for images). I have been working on an app that gets various info about files in a dir, and I noticed that getting mime slowed down the script and increased memory exponentially.

I am aware that getting mime requires reading the file (in some way or other), but at this point I am tempted to use an extension-to-mimetype array lookup instead. Tested on two servers with average output:

```
$file = './larotate.JPG';
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) $t = mime_content_type($file); // "7.107s, 10.4M"
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) $t = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $file); // "7.636s, 10.4M"
for ($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) $t = getimagesize($file); // "0.063s, 0.4M"
```

Time and memory consumed in comment.

If this is just how it is, I can live with that, although I'm slightly surprised. My script gets an array of data about all files in a dir, including size, dimensions, readable, permissions, time etc. Getting mime type slows down the script exponentially, so I am considering using mime lookup array (from extension) instead, although this may not always be accurate.

Comment: Perhaps PHP caches the results of `getimagesize()`; documentation doesn't mention it but you never know. You may want to try with 1,000 different files (or at least 1,000 copies of the same picture, albeit named differently).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks, but in my app I am already loading all (different) files in a dir, and results are consistent. I have tested dirs with 700+ images. What surprised me though, was how slow getting mime type was, also for non-image files. Now I am using mime detection from extension in Javascript, and the PHP runs much faster / lower memory consumption ... Might be some pitfalls, but nothing crucial as of yet.

Comment: MIME magic looks for signatures in the top of the file so there's no real reason for it to be particularly slower than `getimagesize()`, which essentially does the same thing, albeit for a much sorter list of file types. Well, I admit this is a pretty good mystery.

Comment: BTW, in my computer (PHP/7.4 on Win64) `getimagesize()` is roughly twice as fast (not as much difference as in yours) but memory usage seems identical.